# Makefile with multiple wildcards in prerequisites

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile, and I am trying to simplify it.  Any ideas?

```
PROG_NAME=a.out

all: $(PROG_NAME)
    "\nBuilt all\n"

$(PROG_NAME): build/file1.o build/file2.o build/file3.o build/file4.0
    gcc -o $@ $^

#build file1.c and file2.c which are both in ../src directory
build/file%.o: ../src/file%.c
    gcc -I ../inc -o $@ $<

#build file3.c and file4.c which are both in ../src2 directory
build/file%.o: ../src2/file%.c
    gcc -I ../inc -o $@ $<
```

I tried this and it does not work:

```
PROG_NAME=a.out

all: $(PROG_NAME)
    "\nBuilt all\n"

$(PROG_NAME): build/file1.o build/file2.o build/file3.o build/file4.0
    gcc -o $@ $^

#build ../src/file1.c, ../src/file2.c, ../src2/file3.c, and ../src2/file4.c
build/file%.o: ../src/file%.c ../src2/file%.c
    gcc -I ../inc -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simplify it.  The only way would be to use makefile metaprogramming to generate the rules via `eval` or something.

Your attempt will clearly not work, because this:

```
build/file%.o: ../src/file%.c ../src2/file%.c
        gcc -I ../inc -o $@ $<
```

says "for any target `build/fileXXX.o` that you want to build, you can create it by running this `gcc` command on the file `../src/fileXXX.c` if either of the files `../src/fileXXX.c` or `../src2/fileXXX.c` are older than the `.o`".  That's obviously not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to simplify it using the make variable VPATH.

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search

```
PROG_NAME=a.out
VPATH=../src:../src2

all: $(PROG_NAME)
    "\nBuilt all\n"

$(PROG_NAME): build/file1.o build/file2.o build/file3.o build/file4.0
    gcc -o $@ $^

build/file%.o: file%.c
    gcc -I ../inc -o $@ $<
```